# Google Sheets: carry value from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have 2 worksheets in 1 file. I want to bring the value from 1 sheet to another. I only want the value IF it has the name of someone.

Sheet 1

```
+---+-------+--------------+
|   |   A   |       B      |
+---+-------+--------------+
| 1 | Names |    Values    |
+---+-------+--------------+
```

Sheet 2

```
+---+---------------------------------------------+----+
|   |                      A                      |  B |
+---+---------------------------------------------+----+
| 1 | Value from B1 If A1 matches a specific name |    |
+---+---------------------------------------------+----+
```

I've tried `=if(RegexMatch)` but it says it contains 2 arguments

Any suggestions?

Comment: Name of Someone is a team member and these are rankings that change daily so their specific cell may change locations based on ranking

Comment: Okay, so what else can it be: `Empty` or anything else? Also, regarding `but it says it contains 2 arguments` : regexmatch or if? Which part shows it? Kindly note, regexmatch needs two arguments: 1st the text, 2nd the regular expression

Comment: @SeverusSnape yes was just suggesting RegexMatch would be the closest formula I would use but not sure if it's the right one

Comment: Welcome. Have you considered using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks, @marikamitsos I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You want to return a value from one sheet to a second sheet based on whether a given name exists on the first sheet.

Try:
`=vlookup("George",wa_145674!$A$5:$B$8,2,false)`

or this alternative that allows for an non-existent name:
`=iferror(vlookup("Bob",wa_145674!$A$5:$B$8,2,false),"Name not Matched")`

---

**Sheet#1 screenshot**

[image: Sheet#1]

---

**Sheet#2 screenshot**

[image: Sheet#2]

Comment: Yes, VLOOKUP worked thank you all

Comment: No worries. If this answer was helpful, then you might consider "[accepting" it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).